# passing hex command to c function

Tags: c, hex, uart

In the function declaration below for uart write on a mcu, can I pass a hex command?

```
uart_write(const uart_t uart, const uint8_t data);

uart_write(uart_1, 0x56);
```

Comment: What do you mean with "hex command"? `0x56` is a _hexadecimal integer constant_.

Comment: You are using the correct literal for a hexadecimal integer. What exactly are you trying to ask?

Answer (score 1):

yes, you can. However, instead of saying `pass a hex command` it would be more correct to say `pass the value using hex representation`.

Anyway

```
uart_write(uart_1, 0x56);
```

is the same as

```
uart_write(uart_1, 86);  // 86 == 5 * 16 + 6
```

An integer can be given in many formats/representations - the compiler just converts the value into a representation suitable for the compiler. Perhaps this could be interesting for you: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/hex/

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a hexadecimal number, yes you can. To write a hexadecimal number, be sure to precede it with `0x`. You can also write octal (base 8) numbers by preceding it with a `0`

- `0x56`    Hexadecimal 56
- `011`     Octal 11